# Installing provisional profile for Mac when you dont have an Xcode project

Tags: xcode, macos, unity-game-engine, provisioning-profile

How to install a distribution Provisional profile when you dont have a Xcode project..... like i am using Unity3d for my Mac Game .
In my developer account always show 0 devices installed for the provisional profile despite of all tries.

Double click on provisional profile-> Install -> Only Development Provisioning Profiles can be installed in System Preferences. Production Provisioning Profiles are imported within Xcode.

And i tried installing from XCode->window-> Devices->ShowProvisional Profiles -> + -> Adding the new downloaded provisional Profile . Still doesnt work.

but Xcode-> preference-> Accounts -> View Details -> I can see my latest generated provisional profile there

Please help me through this. Thanks in advance and sorry for Bad English

Comment: Try installing Apple configurator https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/apple-configurator/id434433123?mt=12

Comment: What are you trying to do with the distribution provisioning profile?  Unless you are using an enterprise distribution profile, the regular distribution profile is used for build an app that will be deployed through the Apple app store.  It cannot be used to build an app for installing on devices.  Otherwise, developers could use them to build apps for distribution through another app store.

Comment: @wottle
Yeah i was trying to upload a build for App store for submission. And yes i got it through. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the delay in submitting the Answer.

No need to install your Distribution Provisional Profile. You have to check in Xcode-> preference-> Accounts -> View Details -> 
check your Distribution Provisional profile . If not Available just use the refresh button .... it will download automatically.

With distribution provisional profile and certificate you can not install an App on device until unless its downloaded from Mac Store. Or Else you need to build your app through Development Provisional Profile and certificate for Installing on Device and Testing purposes.